# How to color an entire algorithm environment in LaTeX?

Tags: color, algorithms

The entire algorithm environment needs to be colored in blue. While this can be done in a report or article environment, I am unable to get it done in the IEEE Journal templates.

@Masroor : Thanks for the example, but the top and bottom lines are still black in color. How do we make that to be blue as well?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What do you mean by "color the entire algorithm environment"? Do you want to color the text or the background?

Comment: @cfr: I am unable to add a minimal working example as I am unable to duplicate the problem in a simpler document. I cannot attach my original either.

Comment: @Masroor : I want to color the text, including the title of the Algorithm which is given in the top along with the lines that mark the algorithm.

Comment: @user261484 You can't expect that if you can't duplicate the problem then somebody else can do it and is able to read from crystal ball. The problem is in your document which is not reproducible without knowledge about this document. You can try to simplify your document step by step by small steps and to see at what time the problem disappears. Then you examine this last step.

Comment: @wipet: Agreed, I just asked the question, so that in case somebody already experienced such a problem could help me. Masroor has helped me to come up with an example.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.alg}
  \REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
  \ENSURE $y = x^n$

  \STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
  \IF{$n < 0$}
  \STATE $X \leftarrow 1 / x$
  \STATE $N \leftarrow -n$
  \ELSE
  \STATE $X \leftarrow x$
  \STATE $N \leftarrow n$
  \ENDIF
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Redefine the rule colors
% WARNING: may have adverse effects on other float rule color (untested)
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fs@ruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{{\color{blue}\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}}%
  \def\@fs@post{{\color{blue}\kern2pt\hrule\relax}}%
  \def\@fs@mid{{\kern2pt\color{blue}\hrule\kern2pt}}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\section{My Algorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\floatname{algorithm}{\color{blue}Algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{\color{blue}Calculate $y = x^n$}
  \label{alg1}
  \color{blue}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \input{\jobname.alg}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

As you already know, [lipsum](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)
is only for dummy text. [filecontents](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)
is for gen­er­ating and ex­ter­nal file for the
algorithm (which you could put inline anyway, just demonstrating a good
practice).

---

We needed three `\color` commands. First, to change the color of the word,
Algorithm. Second, to change the color of the caption text, and third, to
change the color of actual algorithm.

---

The rule colors have been customized by hacking in to the 
code for, [float](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float).  This is used by the [algorithms](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) package to
create the new type float  `algorithm`.

*(This, I am afraid, may have an adverse effect on other float rules, if any.)*

---

Here is the output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example. Can you check the image in my question?

Comment: The top and bottom lines are also required to be in blue. How to do that?

Comment: @user261484 See the updated answer, which solves the mentioned problem. Please take note of the warning. A little bit occupied to make it more robust.

Comment: @user261484 Perhaps you would like to trim down your question, which does not look nice.

Answer (score 1):

It may be help you.

```latex
\newenvironment{algocolor}{%
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
   \itshape
   \color{blue}
}{}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algocolor}
       \\algo lines
  \end{algocolor}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please -- as usual here -- make your given code snippet be compilable?